# Filling a vector of objects from file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function, which fills a vector of objects from a file, but my program keeps crashing immediatelly upon launch. Here's a brief explanation of what the program should do.
The program itself is based on having multiple specialties, courses (current year of study) and groups. The group object also has a vector, consisting of students from the group. Their member variables are name, social security number (EGN), faculty number (FN) and a map, which contains various tests that the student has made. The pairs of the map are code of test and earned points - students can't have the same code of test multiple times in their map. There are other functions in the program, but they're working just fine, except the ones, which don't have a body yet.
My idea of extracting students from the file, based on their group, is to submit two parameters, when I'm calling the function - one that finds the line with the correct group and another one that is used as a delimiter, in order to stop reading. The file has this type of construction:

```
KST11
Ivan 9402184050 61360133 1 55 2 90 3 78
Kaloqn 9407132530 61360148 1 25 2 80 3 87
KST12
Anton 9402195020 61360138 1 20 2 80 3 92
KST21
KST22
SIT11
SIT12
SIT21
SIT22
```

The ReadFile() function correctly opens the file but it causes the program to crash when it tries to read it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

class CPerson
{
private:
string name;
string EGN;

public:
CPerson()
{
    name=" ";
    EGN=" ";
}

CPerson(const string n, const string e)
{
    name=n;
    EGN=e;
}

string getname()const
{
    return name;
}

string getEGN()const
{
    return EGN;
}

void setname(const string n)
{
    name=n;
}

void setEGN(const string e)
{
    EGN=e;
}

virtual void print() = 0; //1.1

int getAge() const //1.2
{
    int age;
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
    int year = atoi(getEGN().substr(0, 2).c_str());
    int month = atoi(getEGN().substr(2, 2).c_str());
    int day = atoi(getEGN().substr(4, 2).c_str());
    int cyear = 1900 + ltm->tm_year;
    int cmonth = 1 + ltm->tm_mon;
    int cday = 1 + ltm->tm_mday;

    age = cyear - (year + 1900);
    if (cmonth < month)
        age--;
    if (cmonth == month && cday < day)
        age--;
    return age;
}
};

class CStudent: public CPerson
{
private:
string FN;
map<int, int> st_tests;

public:
CStudent()
{
    FN=" ";
}

CStudent(const string n)
{
    FN=n;
}

CStudent(const string o, const string p, const string n):CPerson(o,p)
{
     FN=n;
}

void setFN(const string n)
{
    FN=n;
}

void setst_tests(map<int, int> m)
{
    st_tests=m;
}

string getFN() const
{
    return FN;
}

map<int, int> getst_tests()
{
    return st_tests;
}

void print()
{
    cout<<"Ime: "<<getname()<<endl;
    cout<<"EGN: "<<getEGN()<<endl;
    cout<<"FN: "<<getFN()<<endl;
    map<int, int>::iterator it=st_tests.begin();
    while(it!=st_tests.end())
    {
        cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<endl;
        it++;
    }
}

void add_st_tests(int a, int b)
{
     st_tests.insert(pair<int,int>(a,b));
}

double average() //2.1
{
    double sum=0;
    map<int, int>::iterator it=st_tests.begin();
    for (it=st_tests.begin();it!=st_tests.end();it++)
        sum+=it->second;
    if(st_tests.size()!=0)
        return sum/st_tests.size();
    return -1;
}

int search(const int a) //2.2
{
    map<int, int>::iterator it=st_tests.find(a);
    return it->second;
}

bool operator () (CStudent a, CStudent b) const
{
        return a.average() > b.average();
}
};

class CGroup
{
private:
string spec;
int kurs;
int grupa;
vector<CStudent> students;

public:
string getspec() const
{
    return spec;
}

int getkurs() const
{
    return kurs;
}

int getgrupa() const
{
    return grupa;
}

vector<CStudent> getstudents()
{
    return students;
}

void setstudents(vector<CStudent> a)
{
    students=a;
}

void setspec(const string n)
{
    spec=n;
}

void setkurs(const int n)
{
    kurs=n;
}

void setgrupa(const int n)
{
    grupa=n;
}

CGroup(const string a, const int b, const int c)
{
    spec=a;
    kurs=b;
    grupa=c;

}

void addstudent(CStudent &a)
{
     students.push_back(a);
}

int ReadFile(const string gr, const string stop) //3.1
{
    ifstream st;
    st.open("students.txt",ios::in);
    if(!st)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot open students.txt or file does not exist."<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    string a, b, c, mov;
    int d, e, i=0;
    do
    {
        getline(st,mov);
    }while(mov != gr);
    do
    {
        st >> a >> b >> c;
        students[i].setname(a);
        students[i].setEGN(b);
        students[i].setFN(c);
        do
        {
            st >> d >> e;
            students[i].add_st_tests(d,e);
        }while(st.peek() != '\n' || st.peek() != '\r');
        i++;
        getline(st,mov);
    }while(mov != stop || !st.eof());
    st.close();
}

double averagetest(int a)  //3.2
{
    double sum=0;
    int br=0;
    vector<CStudent>::iterator itt;
    for (itt=students.begin();itt!=students.end();itt++)
    {
        map<int, int>::iterator it=(*itt).getst_tests().find(a);
        sum+=it->second;
        br++;
    }
    cout<<sum/br;
    return sum/br;
}

list<CStudent> averageparam(const int a, const int b) //3.3
{
    list<CStudent> l;
    int i=0;
    vector<CStudent>::iterator itt=students.begin();
    for (itt=students.begin();itt!=students.end();itt++)
    {
        if((*itt).average() >= a && (*itt).average() <= b)
            l.push_back(*itt);
        i++;
    }
    cout<<"List ot studenti sus sreden broi tochki mejdu "<<a<<" - "<<b<<endl;
    list<CStudent>::iterator it=l.begin();
    for (it=l.begin();it!=l.end();it++)
        (*it).print();
    return l;
}

int averageabove(const int a) //3.4
{
    int br=0;
    vector<CStudent>::iterator itt=students.begin();
    for (itt=students.begin();itt!=students.end();itt++)
        if((*itt).average() > a)
            br++;
    cout<<"Broi studenti sus sreden broi tochki nad "<<a<<": "<<br<<endl;
    return br;
}

void averageage(const int a) //3.5
{
    cout<<"Sreden uspeh na "<<a<<" godishni studenti."<<endl;
    vector<CStudent>::iterator itt=students.begin();
    for (itt=students.begin();itt!=students.end();itt++)
    {
        int b=(*itt).getAge();
        if(a == b)
            cout<<(*itt).getname()<<" "<<(*itt).average()<<endl;
    }
}

void beststudent() //3.6
{
    cout<<"Student s nai-visoka uspevaemost."<<endl;
    CStudent temp;
    vector<CStudent>::iterator itt=students.begin();
    for (itt=students.begin();itt!=students.end();itt++)
        if ((*itt).average() > temp.average())
        temp = (*itt);
    temp.print();
}

void sortaverage() //3.7
{
    sort(students.begin(),students.end(),CStudent());
    cout<<"Sortini studenti po sreden broi tochki."<<endl;
    vector<CStudent>::iterator itt=students.begin();
    for (itt=students.begin();itt!=students.end();itt++)
        (*itt).print();
}

void sortasc() //3.8
{

}

void averageage() //3.9
{

}
};

int main()
{
CGroup KST11 ("KST",1,1); KST11.ReadFile("KST11","KST12");
CGroup KST12 ("KST",1,2);
CGroup KST13 ("KST",1,3);
CGroup KST21 ("KST",2,1);
CGroup KST22 ("KST",2,2);
CGroup KST23 ("KST",2,3);
CGroup SIT11 ("SIT",1,1);
CGroup SIT12 ("SIT",1,2);
CGroup SIT13 ("SIT",1,3);
CGroup SIT21 ("SIT",2,1);
CGroup SIT22 ("SIT",2,2);
CGroup SIT23 ("SIT",2,3);
}
```

On this line "KST11.ReadFile("KST11","KST12");", I'm calling the function ReadFile() for the group KST11 by submitting the start and end point of the students, which are going to be read. I'm not completely sure if this is the correct way of doing it though.

Debugging result:

```
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\Users\IvailoCOMP\Desktop\Kursov Proekt N.9\
Adding source dir: C:\Users\IvailoCOMP\Desktop\Kursov Proekt N.9\
Adding file: C:\Users\IvailoCOMP\Desktop\Kursov Proekt N.9\bin\Debug\Kursov Proekt N.exe
Changing directory to: C:/Users/IVAILO~1/Desktop/KURSOV~1.9/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\watcom-1.3\binnt;C:\watcom-1.3\binw;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MINGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname  -quiet  -args C:/Users/IVAILO~1/Desktop/KURSOV~1.9/bin/Debug/KURSOV~1.EXE
done
Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.5
Child process PID: 2748
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In std::string::assign(std::string const&) () ()

Call Stack
#0 0044C9F8 std::string::assign(std::string const&) ()
#1 DFDEDDDC ?? ()
#2 E3E2E1E0 ?? () (??:??)
#3 00402758 check_exception_spec(lsda_header_info*, std::type_info const*, void*, long) ()
#4 ??   ?? ()
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please use a debugger to locate where the crash happens, then edit your question to include only the relevant code.

Comment: However a good idea may be to look if you call e.g. `addstudent` enough number of times before calling `ReadFile`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I'm not familiar of how to utilize the debugging tool, so I'll simply post the messages it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the item to vector before you want to make operation at it

```
    students[i].setname(a);
    students[i].setEGN(b);
    students[i].setFN(c);
```

There was also another issue with 'peek' usage to find the end of a line. The following implementation of `ReadFile` should fix the issues.

```
CStudent readStudent(const std::string& line)
{
   string a, b, c;
   int d, e;
   std::istringstream linestream(line);
   linestream >> a >> b >> c;
   CStudent student;
   student.setname(a);
   student.setEGN(b);
   student.setFN(c);
   while(true)
   {
        linestream >> d >> e;
        if(!linestream.good())
        {
            break;
        }
        student.add_st_tests(d,e);
   }
   return student;
}

void ReadFile(const string gr, const string stop) //3.1
   {
   ifstream st;
   st.open("students.txt",ios::in);
   if(!st)
   {
        cout<<"Cannot open students.txt or file does not exist."<<endl;
        return;
    }
    string mov;
    do
    {
        getline(st,mov);
    } while(mov != gr);
    while(true)
    {
        getline(st,mov);
        if(mov == stop || !st.eof())
        {
            break;
        }
        CStudent student = readStudent(mov);

        students.push_back(student);
    }
    st.close();
}
```

Comment: The exclamation mark in line if(mov == stop || !st.eof()) should be removed, but it's no biggie. Thank you very much for fixing the problematic function.